# TFS 2017 XAML Builds not supported for Git Branch Policies?

Tags: git, xaml, tfs, build-definition

I am trying to set a build definition for a Git Branch Policy in TFS 2017. It seems to me, however, that XAML Build Definitions are not supported in this context (I know XAML builds are marked as obsolete - we plan to change but the amount of work is prohibitive right now). Here's the drop down box that does not include XAML Build Definitions:-

[image: TFS 2017 Git Branch Policy for XAML Build Definition]

Am I missing something or is this just not supported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct it is not supported.

XAML Build are depricated in TFS 2017 and will not be available in tge next version of TFS. VSTS also no longer supports them. You should convert your builds to Team Build to keep parity with new features.

Comment: Thanks, Martin, I will stop banging my head against the wall now.